# Response tab contents in Chrome Developer Tools are overwritten by later HTTP response?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there a bug in Chrome Developer Tools presentation of HTTP response bodies?
In that case - any known workarounds?

I'm using the Chrome Developer Tools to view HTTP responses. I do a PUT and later a GET
using the same URL. When examining the response from the PUT and GET they are the
same. I'm using the "Response" tab under "Network" which shows the body of the HTTP response.
The response codes from the "Header" tab are correct for the PUT but the "Response" 
tab shows the contents (body) of the response for the GET.

It seems the body of the response for the first request (the PUT) kept by Chrome Developer 
is overwritten by the later response body from the GET for the same URL.

I've tried the same with Firefox Developer Tools and the response body for the PUT and GET
are proper (and NOT the same). Also RESTClient shows the proper result. 
So I'm pretty convinced the REST Service works fine.

It may be some setting that I missed but it seems odd to overwrite the response
from a PUT with that from a later GET using whatever settings I'm using?

I'm using Chrome Version 21.0.1180.75 running on Mac OSX 10.7.4.

I'm not sure whether this has been reported before, I could find similar reports, i.e.
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/iRKQd3rL3NY%5B1-25%5D

but that didn't seem to be the exact same problem.

Is this a known problem? Any remedy?
I could of course use another tool but I'm otherwise happy with Chrome Developer Tools.

/ Mats

Comment: The Chromium team seems to have fixed this:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=133021

Still not working in Chrome Version 21.0.1180.79 but hopefully the fix is in the release pipe.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Google Chrome Version 21.0.1180.82, just released.

I have done the same PUT followed by a GET that had the bug in earlier
releases (21.0.1180.75 and 21.0.1180.79) in the now latest release (21.0.1180.82).
I works fine in 21.0.1180.82, showing different response bodies for the GET and the PUT.

Case closed.